# Simple php if !empty-function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to simply echo a link (set in a custom field in Wordpress), when the corresponding field is not empty.

I tried the following, but the output is missing the link. Only the field as plain text gets printed

```
<?php $projekt_link = the_field('link');                                    
  if(!empty($projekt_link)){                                              
    echo '<a href="'.$projekt_link->name.'" class="button">Zum Projekt</a>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: What does var_dump($projekt_link) return ?

Comment: It looks like `the_field`, by default, echoes out the field value, not returns it. You probably want `get_field` instead.

Comment: You shouldn't use `empty()` with strings, just arrays (and it's generally redundant, but clearer to read).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Advance Custom Fields` plugin, then the correct syntax is

```
$projekt_link = get_field('link');
```